# CCFL'S wiring in a series

Tags: wiring, inverter, series

I’m hoping someone here can help me with a long overdue project. I’m trying to figure out how to wire multiple CCFLS to one power source + inverter... so far not much success on my own.

I’m currently able to run up to 3 CCFL's in a series, at varying lengths either 3x 6”/152mm or 3x 12”305mm, off of an AC/DC converter  + inverter
(Input: 120V/60Hz/12VA Output: 6V/800ma)

Can anyone shed light on what range of AC/DC converter + inverter I would need to run 6-12 CCFLS in a series?  [Here’s](https://azurebumble.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/boom_01.jpg?w=655) an example of this series in action, really want to figure out how to do it myself. Any help appreciated!

Some specs I found on CCFLS; keep in mind the one's I have came as is from a liquidation center, they are just loose CCFL's no manufacturers info etc.

Inverter Requires 12 VDC (can go between 14VDC-6VDC safely) and Generates as much as 1000VAC to power lamp tube. The lamp requires 800-1000VAC (?)
Power consumption between 350-400ma at 12VDC (4.2-4.8watts). Inverter needs 12VDC, wall plugs give 120VAC, AC/DC converter is fine as long as you’re getting between 350-400ma to the inverter.

Specs from one CCFL producer: 
For a 6”/152mm Cathode:
For a 12”/305mm Cathode according to this provider:
Starting Circuit Voltage 1000VS (Vms)
Operating Lamp Voltage:  400 (Vms)
Operating Lamp Current: IL (mAims) 5
For a 12”/305mm Cathode according to this provider:
Starting Circuit Voltage 1750VS (Vms)
Operating Lamp Voltage:  780 (Vms)
Operating Lamp Current: IL (mAims) 5

Comment: What are the specs for your CCFLs? Datasheets available? We need information about the requirements of the parts you're wanting to use before we can tell you how to power them.

Comment: Hey, I just added what little info I have on the CCFLs to my question. Thanks Robherc

Answer (score 1):

From what I was able to find from Google resulte; this looks like a pretty straightforward power-supply decision.

I found a range of dkfferent CCFL inverters ($40-$350USD) for powering 1-12 CCFL tubes per inverter at [lcdparts.net](http://www.lcdparts.net/U6_3D.aspx) (looks like 6 tubes for $80 is their best price/tube for running your 6/12 tube setup you mentioned).

As for your AC/DC converter sizing, most of the tubes I'm seeing are 6W and under; so I'd recommend sourcing a converter capable of at least 8W per tube you plan to power.

This extra few watts of avail. supply should compensate for inverter inefficiencies, give a little power for your pulse drive circuitry for your phased signage image you're trying to replicate (BTW, I'm fairly certain that image was PhotoShopped), and help keep you fro  overheating your supply by running it too close to max output kf you end up uskng this project for extended periods at a time.